# Is there SQL Query using SQL Server 2016 to display only record with no duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have

[image: Query results for all records]

How to query so that the results will only display record having no duplicate without hard coding? See results

[image: Query Results using hardcode]

Comment: Please share your table details and the queries you are using.

Comment: In your example there is no duplicate records at all

Answer (score 3):

If you want `empcode`s with no duplicates, then one simple way uses aggregation:

```
select empcode, min(leavecode) as leavecode
from t
group by empcode
having count(*) = 1;
```

This works, because if there is only one row for an `empcode`, then `min(leavecode)` is *the* `leavecode`.

An alternative method uses window functions:

```
select empcode, leavecode
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by empcode) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

Or, if `leavecode`s are unique when there are duplicates, perhaps the most efficient way:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.emp_code = t.empcode and t2.leavecode <> t.leavecode
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You just select those records that have the `empcode` in a table of empcodes that only have one occurrence.

```
SELECT
  empcode,
  leavecode
FROM mytable
WHERE empcode in (
  SELECT empcode FROM mytable GROUP BY empcode HAVING count(1)=1
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps me a lot.